# 0 files indexed after migrating from sonarqube 5.0.1 to 5.1.2

Tags: sonarqube

After migrating our project from sonarqube 5.0.1 to 5.1.2 we get no results after analysing. I gues its because sonar runner is indexing 0 files....The configuration, like basedir, didnt change. Does anyone having an idea?

```
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to SUCCESS
[workspace] $ C:\Users\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation\SonarRunner\bin\sonar-runner.bat -e -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://zaphod:9000/ ******** ******** -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=C:\Users\Jenkins\.jenkins\jobs\KISSsoftCRM_develop\workspace -Dsonar.sources=src/api,src/main -Dsonar.junit.reportsPath=build/test-results -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPath=build/jacoco/test.exec -Dsonar.jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero=true -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0.0 -Dsonar.java.binaries=build/classes -Dsonar.modules=CRMUtil -Dsonar.projectKey=com.kisssoft.crm.util -Dsonar.java.libraries=build/libs -Dsonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco -Dsonar.projectName=CRMUtil_develop
C:\Users\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation\SonarRunner
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.8.0_25 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Windows 7 6.1 amd64
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: Runner configuration file: C:\Users\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation\SonarRunner\conf\sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: NONE
INFO: Default locale: "de_DE", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Work directory: C:\Users\Jenkins\.jenkins\jobs\KISSsoftCRM_develop\workspace\.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.1.2
14:35:00.881 INFO  - Load global repositories
14:35:01.213 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=334ms
14:35:01.215 INFO  - Server id: 20150802141341
14:35:01.218 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\Jenkins\.sonar\cache
14:35:01.228 INFO  - Install plugins
14:35:01.283 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
14:35:01.293 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar
14:35:04.103 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
14:35:06.921 INFO  - Load project repositories
14:35:07.002 INFO  - Load project repositories (done) | time=81ms
14:35:07.002 INFO  - Load project settings
14:35:08.261 INFO  - Load technical debt model
14:35:08.287 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
14:35:08.975 INFO  - -------------  Scan CRMUtil
14:35:08.981 INFO  - Load module settings
14:35:09.162 INFO  - Load rules
14:35:09.230 INFO  - Base dir: C:\Users\Jenkins\.jenkins\jobs\KISSsoftCRM_develop\workspace\CRMUtil
14:35:09.230 INFO  - Working dir: C:\Users\Jenkins\.jenkins\jobs\KISSsoftCRM_develop\workspace\.sonar\com.kisssoft.crm.util_CRMUtil
14:35:09.231 INFO  - Source paths: src/api, src/main
14:35:09.232 INFO  - Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: de_DE
14:35:09.232 INFO  - Index files
14:35:09.265 INFO  - 0 files indexed
14:35:09.751 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
14:35:09.753 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=2ms
14:35:09.753 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor
14:35:09.770 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=17ms
14:35:09.770 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor
14:35:09.791 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor (done) | time=21ms
14:35:09.791 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor
14:35:09.801 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor (done) | time=10ms
14:35:09.801 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor
14:35:10.115 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor (done) | time=314ms
14:35:10.115 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
14:35:10.115 INFO  - SCM Sensor is disabled
14:35:10.115 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=0ms
14:35:10.115 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor
14:35:10.115 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=0ms
14:35:10.147 INFO  - Loaded quality gate 'SonarQube way'
14:35:10.204 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2015-08-02)
14:35:10.212 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2015-07-03, analysis of Tue Jun 30 23:09:17 CEST 2015)
14:35:10.215 INFO  - Compare to previous version (2015-07-28)
14:35:11.237 INFO  - Execute decorators...
14:35:11.745 INFO  - -------------  Scan CRMUtil_develop
14:35:11.746 INFO  - Load module settings
14:35:11.772 INFO  - Base dir: C:\Users\Jenkins\.jenkins\jobs\KISSsoftCRM_develop\workspace
14:35:11.772 INFO  - Working dir: C:\Users\Jenkins\.jenkins\jobs\KISSsoftCRM_develop\workspace\.sonar
14:35:11.772 INFO  - Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: de_DE
14:35:11.776 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
14:35:11.776 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=0ms
14:35:11.776 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor
14:35:11.782 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor (done) | time=6ms
14:35:11.783 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor
14:35:11.786 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor (done) | time=2ms
14:35:11.786 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor
14:35:11.793 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor (done) | time=7ms
14:35:11.793 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
14:35:11.793 INFO  - SCM Sensor is disabled
14:35:11.793 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=0ms
14:35:11.793 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor
14:35:11.793 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=0ms
14:35:11.819 INFO  - Loaded quality gate 'SonarQube way'
14:35:11.823 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2015-08-02)
14:35:11.825 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2015-07-03, analysis of Tue Jun 30 23:09:17 CEST 2015)
14:35:11.827 INFO  - Compare to previous version (2015-07-28)
14:35:13.311 INFO  - Execute decorators...
14:35:13.527 INFO  - Store results in database
14:35:13.792 INFO  - Analysis reports generated in 41ms, dir size=169 bytes
14:35:13.815 INFO  - Analysis reports compressed in 22ms, zip size=777 bytes
14:35:13.853 INFO  - Analysis reports sent to server in 38ms
14:35:13.853 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://zaphod:9000/dashboard/index/com.kisssoft.crm.util
14:35:13.853 INFO  - Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report.
```

Comment: are you scanning against Java? Also have you used any suffixes within your project?

Comment: is module located directly in parent directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably forget to copy extensions/plugins from the old install to the new one. As a result you don't have any language plugin installed. Please provide server startup logs to confirm.

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue, i diddnt know that the plugins had to be copied from old version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we are building it against Java 8 on Jenkins.
This is the configuration:

```
sonar.projectKey=com.kisssoft.crm.util
sonar.projectName=CRMUtil_develop
sonar.projectVersion=1.0.0
sonar.sources=src/api,src/main
# sonar.tests=src/test
sonar.modules=CRMUtil
sonar.junit.reportsPath=build/test-results
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=build/jacoco/test.exec
sonar.jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero=true
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.java.binaries=build/classes
sonar.java.libraries=build/libs
```

When i have a look at the base dir it seems correct in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

it seems that SonarQube is missing the needed plugins. I have faced the same issue, but after installing them through settings->Update Center everything worked fine.

please check the same with your configuration and install all required plugins within Sonarqube.